# How to collect ArrayList in a single Activity

Tags: android

i am making an application and the main activity of the application has 6 image buttons. 
the code for the main activity is

package org.personal.reader;

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements
Button.OnClickListener  {

    ArrayList<String> activeURL =  new ArrayList<String>();
    private Button Done, Refresh;
    int i=0;
    private ImageButton B1, B2, B3, B4, B5, B6;
    public static final String LOG_TAG = "Main Activity";

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        Done = (Button)findViewById(R.id.DONE);
        Done.setOnClickListener(this);
        Refresh = (Button)findViewById(R.id.REFRESH);
        Refresh.setOnClickListener(this);
        B1 = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.news1);
        B1.setOnClickListener(this);
        B2 = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.sports1);
        B2.setOnClickListener(this);
        B3 = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.weather1);
        B3.setOnClickListener(this);
        B4 = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.entertainment1);
        B4.setOnClickListener(this);
        B5 = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.health1);
        B5.setOnClickListener(this);
        B6 = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.tech1);
        B6.setOnClickListener(this);
    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if ( v==B1)
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Reader.class);
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
            startActivity(intent);

        }

        if ( v==B2 )
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Reader2.class);
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
            startActivity(intent);
        }

        if ( v==B3 )
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Reader3.class);
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
            startActivity(intent);
        }

        if ( v==B4 )
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Reader4.class);
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
            startActivity(intent);
        }

        if ( v==B5 )
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Reader5.class);
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
            startActivity(intent);
        }

        if ( v==B6 )
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Reader6.class);
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
        if (v==Done)
        {   ArrayList<String> array =add();      
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putStringArrayList("DONE", array);
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Aggregator.class);
            myIntent.putExtra("agg", array);
            startActivity(myIntent);
        }
    }
    public ArrayList<String> add() 
    {
        Bundle bundle=this.getIntent().getExtras();
        ArrayList<String> temp = bundle.getStringArrayList("reader");
        ArrayList<String> temp1 = new ArrayList<String>();
        temp1=temp;
        if (temp1!=null)
            activeURL.addAll(temp1);
    return activeURL;
   }
}
```

on clicking on any of the radio button a new activity opens.
the code for one of the activity is

```
public class Reader extends Activity implements
        Button.OnClickListener {

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    private RadioButton RB1, RB2, RB3, RB4, RB5;
    private Button Done;
    ArrayList<String> activeURL1 = new ArrayList<String>();
    public static final String LOG_TAG = "Activity 1";

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main1);
        RB1 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.BBC);
        RB2 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.Guardian);
        RB3 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.msnbc);
        RB4 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.Sky);
        RB5 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.FOX);
        Done = (Button) findViewById(R.id.DONE);
        Done.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override

    public void onClick(View v) {
        String[] array;
        array = new String[5];

        array[0] = "http://feeds.bbci.co.uk/news/world/rss.xml";
        array[1] = "http://feeds.guardian.co.uk/theguardian/rss";
        array[2] = "http://rss.msnbc.msn.com/id/3032506/device/rss/rss.xml";
        array[3] = "http://news.sky.com/sky-news/rss/world-news/rss.xml";
        array[4] = "http://www.foxnews.com/about/rss/feedburner/foxnews/most-popular";

        if (RB1.isChecked() == true)
            activeURL1.add(array[0]);
        if (RB2.isChecked() == true)
            activeURL1.add(array[1]);
        if (RB3.isChecked() == true)
            activeURL1.add(array[2]);
        if (RB4.isChecked() == true)
            activeURL1.add(array[3]);
        if (RB5.isChecked() == true)
            activeURL1.add(array[4]);

        if(v==Done)
        {   
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putStringArrayList("DONE", activeURL1);
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(Reader.this,MainActivity.class);
            myIntent.putExtra("reader", activeURL1);
            startActivity(myIntent);
        }
    }
}
```

i have 6 activities... i need to pass an array Arraylist from each activity and collect it a Arraylist in MainActivity... finally the pass this list to another class.

How to pass this list from all the activities and collect it in the main activity?

Comment: you want to send arraylist from each activity you start ??

Comment: yes.. they should be added to a Arraylist present in the MainActivity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have an arraylist you wish to have accessible throughout the system, you can place a holder arraylist in the Application class and provide getters and setters so that they system can utilize it globally. If it only has to be move from one activity to another once, I would recommend placing it in the bundle.

Answer (score 0):

By trying that maybe it is working :

```
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putStringArrayList("DONE", activeURL1);
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(Reader.this,MainActivity.class);
        myIntent.**putStringArrayListExtra**("reader", activeURL1);
        startActivity(myIntent);
```

Best,

Answer (score 0):

I would stay away from passing an arraylist from each activity as this can lead to some memory issues as I have found out.  One of the better ways is to create global list that all activities can see.  I did this with my bluetoothAdapter since retrieving it was a little slow and setting it global was the faster implementation... I would do the same with your array list

```
public class MyStates extends Application {

    /** The bluetooth adapter for the phone **/
    private BluetoothAdapter blueToothAdapter;

    public BluetoothAdapter getBtState() {
        return this.blueToothAdapter;
    }

    public void setBtState(BluetoothAdapter cust) {
        this.blueToothAdapter = cust;
    }

}
```